# Can't see how to download large files from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I cannot see how to download some videos to my Dropbox. Somebody shared a folder of videos with me.  If I try to download the whole folder, I get an "error message".

> The zip file is too large, please add it to your Dropbox

(I'm not keen on buying Dropbox space for myself, just to download a friend's file.)

[image]

I read I can download individual files but I don't see the option. When I play the video I get a message saying

> The clip displayed is a preview. To view the entire video, download or add it to your Dropbox.

[image]

Comment: Can you open the folder and download individual files / unzip the file online?

Comment: @Djave I am not sure what form they were uploaded in.. i'd have thought they are folders that dropbox lets or doesn't let you download as a zip. When you double click a folder, it opens it, I don't think that is unzipping

Comment: I can see a download option now.. for the individual files that I could not see before, I saw it actually as I was writing the question but I wanted to post an answer with screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download link when download a folder is in a completely different place to the download link to download individual files.

The download link when downloading a folder is as the screenshot in the question shows, is bright blue and in the top right.

But the download link for downloading files, is black and in the bottom right.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can create a new folder in your drop box folder in your PC and then move the entire folder to it. Drop box will move all the files and content to the new folder.
Then you can simply edit the new folder with a different name.